# Prediction using CRFs for time series data

Tags: time-series, prediction

I have a little confusion about validity of some predictions I am making using a CRF model I have trained.

The CRF model is trained on some input time-series, and when making predictions, I am passing the entire sequence to be labelled to the model. I have a concern that this is incorrect for the problem, since what I want is predictions for each observation in the time series up to that point (as if it were coming in, in real time), and I have the feeling that predictions are being made using the entire sequence (mainly due to references I see about a forward-backward algorithm for inference).

Do I need to pass only the sequence up to "what has currently been observed" in order to get a causally predicted label for that point in time, or is there such a thing as "forward only" prediction for such scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

You want to do time-series prediction, but the CRFs are used for sequential supervised learning.

> There are two key differences between time-series prediction and
>   sequential supervised learning.
>
> First in sequential supervised learning, the entire sequence x1,...,
>   xT is available before we make any predictions of the y values,
>   whereas in time-series prediction, we have only a prefix of the
>   sequence up to the current time t + 1.
>
> Second, in time-series analysis, we have the true observed y values up
>   to time t, whereas in sequential supervised learning, we are not given
>   any y values and we must predict them all.

taken from [Machine Learning for Sequential Data: A Review](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/publications/mlsd-ssspr.pdf)